# Using Cambridge's "short-title reference system"

Tags: citations, citation-style

Does anyone have experience using the Cambridge UP's "short-title reference system" or even just know of a work that uses it. I'm copy-editing for some extra cash but the style guide they have online is really not very helpful.

The very first reference I've tried to come up with, for example, is a translated work, and they have no indication of how to include the translator in the citation other than saying that it should be there.

My best guess is:

Author's name, Title of Work, Translator's name (trans.)(Place of publication: Publisher, Year), p. page number.

I guess the main issue is I can't tell if "(trans.)" should be in parentheses or not. This is just my best guess based on the example given for a book with an editor, which is "Editor's name (ed.)"

Thank you for any advice!

Answer (score -1):

I can't give you direct advice about the Cambridge short title but there are quite a lot of applications to go from bibtex to different reference styles. I would suggest using one of those to help. I found the easiest way to do this is to add items to zotero and then export as bibliography, they have hundreds of styles based on journals as well as common ones like Harvard and Chicago Manual.